# adding objects to an already existing javascript object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, javascript-objects

I have a javascript object that contains addresses as follows

```
var addressList = [
    {"AddressID":"10011","AddressType":"Delivery","AddressLine1":"4 Caerleon Drive","AddressLine2":"Bittern","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 5LF","Country":"United Kingdom","ContactID":"10011"},
    {"AddressID":"10012","AddressType":"Home","AddressLine1":"526 Butts Road","AddressLine2":"Sholing","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 1DJ","Country":"England","ContactID":"10011"}
]
```

I want to add another "address" to it so i have somthing like the following

```
[
{"AddressID":"10011","AddressType":"Delivery","AddressLine1":"4 Caerleon Drive","AddressLine2":"Bittern","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 5LF","Country":"United Kingdom","ContactID":"10011"},
{"AddressID":"10012","AddressType":"Home","AddressLine1":"526 Butts Road","AddressLine2":"Sholing","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 1DJ","Country":"England","ContactID":"10011"},
{"AddressID":"10013","AddressType":"Home","AddressLine1":"5436 Bfds Road","AddressLine2":"Sherly","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 1DJ","Country":"England","ContactID":"10011"}
]
```

i cant figure out how to do this ?

Comment: I assume this isn't your actual code, as it is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: Your first JavaScript does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add a new object to the array:

```
addressList.push({"AddressID":"10013","AddressType":"Home","AddressLine1":"5436 Bfds Road","AddressLine2":"Sherly","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 1DJ","Country":"England","ContactID":"10011"});
```

Comment: will that push associative arrays/objects ?

Comment: This will only work if addressList is an array.  In his example, it's an object.  He needs to create an array first and then push objects to it.

Comment: @saml: But it's an array `var addressList = [...]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you're encountering, but the probable problem you're running into is that the first snippet you give is a javascript Object, and the second snippet is an Array.  You'd need to so something like:

```
var addressList = [];
addressList.push({"AddressID":"10011",...});
```

You could then iterate over the list using a forEach:

```
addressList.forEach(function(address) {
    alert(address.AddressID);
    doSomethingWithAddress(address);
});
```

You can read more about Arrays on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

addressList.push({AddressID: 1234, Country: 'Foo', ...});